# How long do Microsoft Learn Sandbox created resources persist before deletion?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure so I decided to use Microsoft Learn Sandbox to fool around and find out.

After following this [exercise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/host-a-web-app-with-azure-app-service/3-exercise-create-a-web-app-in-the-azure-portal?pivots=csharp), I managed to create a web app with a specific name.

After writing a simple GitHub workflow to build and deploy my application, I found out that my webapp is not accessible anymore. Of course it makes sense for a ressource to be deleted after the sandbox has expired and I should have thought about it before but I cannot create a new webapp using the same specific name in my personal Azure Pay-per-use subscription as I a greeted with an error explaining me that this name is not available.

After a bit of browsing I read various answers about the retention time of these resources, which can vary from a few minutes up to three months.

I understand that this retention system exists to allow users to restore deleted resources and that it can be configured by various policies but I could not find a specific response for the ones relative to Learn Sandbox.

When can I expect this resource to be deleted from the system so I can use my specific name again ?

[image: New WebApp error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 24 Hours after sandbox expiration

The previous answer did not answer my question, regarding the lifecycle of the ressources, and not the sandbox.

A few days after I posted this question, I was able to create a new web app with the specific name I wanted but I felt frustrated not understanding the underlying rule.

I tried again and created a web app with another specific name in a sandbox around 6 pm and let it expire. The next day I tried to create a web app with the same name in my personal subscription at regular intervals until the name was available again, around 10pm.

This time gap being 28 hours, the sandbox lifecycle being 4 hours, we can suppose those resources are purged 24 hours after sandbox expiration.

Answer (score 1):

> **How long does the sandbox stay around?**
> The sandbox environment created for a module is available for four consecutive hours to ensure that you can finish the module. The Microsoft Learn exercises are meant to be finished in one sitting, in an hour or less.

You can actually verify this in the [Sandbox FAQ - How long does the sandbox stay around?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/support/faq?pivots=sandbox#how-long-does-the-sandbox-stay-around)

Comment: I obviously read that FAQ before asking. What bothers me is that this sandbox is over a day old. My old web app does not exist anymore. I could not find it using the CLI but i guess it still exists in a "bin" somewhere, or maybe someone created a web app with the exact same specific name.

Comment: You obviously did not mention that in your question. What bothers me is that someone took their time to write something that answers your question, and you respond this way. Long story short: a sandbox is to play with. If you need anything else, [open your own (free) subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/).